# Image fade-in doesnt keep final alpha

Tags: android, image, animation

I have an image that fades in once the page is loaded.  However the final alpha of the image that is set in the animation is not kept.  I have the following (simple) xml for my image:

```
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Then I have the animation file which fades in the image:

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha 
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="0.6"  
    android:duration="2000"/> 
    </set>
```

Then finally the code which loads the image:

```
    body =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    body.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), background));
    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein_bg);
    body.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
```

So how can I get the final alpha of the image to stay after the animation is complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was using body.setBackgroundDrawable() instead of body.setImageDrawable().  Of course I still need to add setAlpha() in there as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `.setFillAfter()` method call before you you start the animation like this:

```
myFadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
body.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the background drawable, try setting the alpha on the ImageView `setAlpha(float)` that should retain the alpha value that you're eventually animating to.

Comment: I've tried that but it still did not work.  I added body.setAlpha(20); before the animation but at the end of the animation it still went to its full color.